# Attempting to do javascript 'confirm' on a button in the code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some code on my asp.net page that looks like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="if (confirm('ARE YOU SURE?  This cannot be undone except by IT at great cost!')) { PurgeCourse(); }" value="Purge Course Comments" id="Button2" name="Button2" />
```

I'm replacing this with statements in the code behind.  So far, my statements looks like this:

```
            var Button2 = new Button();
            Button2.Text = "Purge Course Comments";
            Button2.OnClientClick = "javascript: PurgeCourse();";
            pageButtons.Controls.Add(Button2);
```

This works great in the button that is added and the PurgeCourse function is called when the button is pressed.

However, I want to add a 'confirm' (as in the original page code above) so that the user must confirm their choice.  Is there a way that I can add that same 'confirm' functionality to what I have above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the JS you originally had into your new buttons client click handler:

```
Button2.OnClientClick = "if (confirm('ARE YOU SURE?  This cannot be undone except by IT at great cost!')) { PurgeCourse(); }"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Although I'm sure the other answers would've worked, too, this one fit the bill in what I was trying to accomplish without having to add another function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Javascript function in your ASPX html that has the logic from your first piece of code in the question. Then, call that function on `Button2.OnClientClick`.

I.E. in the page:

```
function foo () {
    if (confirm( /*.. snip ..*/ ) { /* .. snip .. */ }
}
```

In the code behind:

```
Button2.OnclientClick = "javascript: foo()";
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling directly PurgeCourse(), create an intermediary function

```
function confirmAndPurgeCourse() {
   if (confirm('you sure'?')) PurgeCourse();
}
```

and invoke it in

```
Button2.OnClientClick = "javascript: confirmAndPurgeCourse();";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function

```
function purgeCourseWithConfirm() {
    if (confirm('ARE YOU SURE?  This cannot be undone except by IT at great cost!')) 
    { 
       PurgeCourse();
    }
}
```

Then `Button2.OnClientClick = "javascript: purgeCourseWithConfirm();";`